# Node's global variable vs. a variable called global created within a react component SSR

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-side, server-side-rendering

If I have a SSR react application running on node with a component that sets a variable like `let global = {}` and then do something like `global.name = 'sam'`, would this global variable replace/overwrite node's global object OR would this global variable just be within the scope of the react component? Would this object be garbage collected when the component unmounts or would it stay in memory as node's global object?

I know that it is not best practice to use `global` as a variable name, but just wondering if this may lead to a memory leak.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] and explain the motivation behind the `global` object in a SSR situation. I feel like this is another case of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/254800), where Y is you thinking that a `global` object is the solution and if you took a step back, you'd see that the problem you're trying to solve is really X and that is what you should be asking about.

Comment: Persisting a global state with SSR often include dumping the serialized data somewhere in the page and parsing it once on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

The `let global` variable will only replace node's `global` in the scope the new variable is defined in.

```
console.log(global) // Object [global] {...}
function go(){
  let global = {}
  console.log(global) // {}
}
go()
console.log(global) // Object [global] {...}
```

<sub>Don't use a variable named `global` when using node.</sub>

Comment: thanks! so what if inside the `go` function, I do something like `global.name = 'bob'`. I would updating the `global` object in the scope of `go()`, right? when garbage collection happens, would the `global` object within the `go` function be collected?

Comment: Yes it set name on the in scope `global` and it will be gc'd